# Creating custom operators for swift Range types

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, range

I thought it would be fun (and possibly useful) to add some custom operator for Swift ranges. For example, to grow the range by one:

```
postfix func ++ <I : ForwardIndexType where I : Comparable>(inout lhs: Range<I>) -> Range<I> {
    lhs.endIndex++
    return lhs
}
```

However, when I try:

```
(1...2)++
```

I get:

> Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to operand of type (Range)

Any ideas or should I give up?

EDIT:

I also got the problem with passing ranges as parameters:

```
someFunc(range : Range<Int>) {
   range++
```

Comment: Try using an operator that doesn't have an existing meaning.

Comment: The range literal is an immutable value which can't be passed as `inout`. Assigning to a mutable var first works: `var x = 1...2 ; x++`.

Comment: OK - let me get back on this, because I haver other problem examples as well.

Comment: Right ... it is a mutability problem in all my test cases that fail, I believe. I had a similar error with parameters (read only by default). I will up-vote, but I am out of votes for minute. Give it a few hours ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hamstergene is right. You can't `++` a range literal, just like you can't `++` a regular old `Int`.

For example, you can't write:

```
let x = 5++
```

Your operator works if you assign the range to a variable and then call the operator:

```
var r = 1..<3

r++      // r == 1..<4
```